# How to build text-only fadein/fadeout carousel in JS (Bootstrap-like)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'd like to implement a fade-in/fade-out text only carousel like on the header of [this website](http://www.awerest.com/demo/myway/light/index.html).

I looked at the code and it seems that it was done with bootstrap.

Since I don't really want to implement the whole bootstrap thing only for this, is there a way to do something similar with a few lines of CSS and Javascript (Im a total newbie in JS)?

Many thanks for your help

HTML of the website I took as example:

```
<div id="carousel_fade_intro" class="carousel slide">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="active item">
                                    <h1>Multi-purpose template</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <h1>designed for portfolio, agency</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <h1>or landing page.</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <h1>It's easy to customize</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <h1>to fit any brand.</h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at jQuery's fadeIn and fadeOut methods.

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

The example you linked toggles classes on each item in a loop and uses css transitions to control the fades.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I'm not good enough (yet) to adapt this to my needs